# How does Visual Studio 2017 know that IISExpress is selected in Debug Properties?

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I have a LaunchSettings file, which looks like this:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5002",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "MvcClient": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5002"
    }
  }
}
```

If I right click on the project and selected Properties/Debug, then the Profile selected is: IIS Express.  If I add docker support to the project, then a new entry is added to launchsettings.json and the profile changes in Debug Properties to: Docker.

How does Visual Studio know what to select? I was expecting to see a JSON property called: Selected (with values of true or false) under each profile.

The reason I ask is because I cannot change the Profile in Debug Properties i.e. if I do attempt to change the Profile, then the save button does not work and once I close the window it changes back to what it was.  Why is this? Note that I have tried this in two separate projects in two separate machines.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers indicate where in the UI you change it but not how VS actually knows what you've selected. The answer to this is in the `___.csproj.user` file. If you check, you'll see something like this:

```
<ActiveDebugProfile>IIS Express</ActiveDebugProfile>
```

If you change it, it changes in-memory. If you "save all" or try to run using a different profile, the change will be persisted to the user file.

Answer (score 2):

You can't save the selection persistently in the launchsettings.json, the Debug-Settings are just for configuring the profile, not for selecting it -  you need to change the profile using the small arrow next to the Debug-Button to set it for your current Visual Studio session:
[image]

When using the command-line you can also set the Launch-Profile by using the --launch-profile - Parameter:

> dotnet run --launch-profile 'MvcClient'

IIS Express-profiles do not work with dotnet run.